# WinRT barcode scanner component

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, barcode

I have a Windows Store (Metro) application.  I need to add support for scanning barcodes.

I tried using ZXing first.  From what I was able to get working, you actually need to click and save an image for it to do the processing.  There's no nice overlay of a red line "scanner" nor does it process a live feed.  This isn't a very elegant solution.  It works far better on Android.  Basically, this won't work as I need a constant video and a constant search for a barcode to be in focus.

This blog (http://www.soulier.ch/?p=1275&lang=en) mentions that extrapolating a frame out of a WinRT video stream is not allowed in managed code which means I'd need to use C++.

So, are there any components out there that do this?  Anything free or paid that I can get that would be written in C++ and can find and extrapolate a barcode?  Learning C++ is not on my bucket list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture frames while displaying a preview with C# only. Here's an example control that does it:

https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/CameraCaptureControl/CameraCaptureControl.cs

Basically you need to create a [`MediaCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) object and associate it with a [`CaptureElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx) control to display the preview. Then you can use [`CapturePhotoToStreamAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700840.aspx) to capture a frame to a stream of your selected encoding format and then have a go at it with your bar code reading code.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [lib](https://github.com/stepheUp/VideoScanZXing4WP81) for WinRT using ZXing & Imaging SDK.
It works well  (but does not include any additional focus feature).
There is a lib and a sample app that you can try.
It works for barcodes and QRCode (barcode by default but just change the optional parameter in the scan function code to use QRCode)